# Connecting circles in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to connect my circles with line going between them in CSS3 but i don't know how to.

```css
.circle
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.circle
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 2px black solid;
  position: relative;
}

.circle:before {
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: -20px;
}

.circle.last:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle last"></div>
```

Comment: Looks almost gr8, tho i don't know how to delete the line from the last circle :l

Comment: @nehel add class "last"on the last circle and use **.circle.last:before{ display: none;}**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line div like this:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

From here you will then have to position them correctly in css.
You can make a very small fixed height and width and put a border on it to make a line.